# Some unknown error shows when macos terminal starts: _nomad_completionetup

Tags: macos, terminal

Everytime when I start terminal, these two lines shows, it doesn't affect anything but still annoying.
Have you seen this on your Mac?

_nomad_completionetup:[:4: unknown condition: -gt

_nomad_completionetup:[:4: unknown condition: -eq

[the terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N04GS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I checked my .zshrc file and commented out

source ~/.nomad-autocompletion.sh

Then the error disappears.